# exception while using text datatype in database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database from on which i am running a query . I am getting this exception . I think it has something to do with he space in the query how can solve it.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "413": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, number, name, macid, type FROM favorites WHERE _id=(652) 413-6525
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at com.honda.phone.DBAdapter.isPresent(DBAdapter.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at com.honda.phone.FavoriteSelectionActivity.onClick(FavoriteSelectionActivity.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2978):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is the code

```
public boolean isPresent(String number) throws SQLException 
    {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_NUMBER, 
                        KEY_NAME,
                        KEY_MACID,
                        KEY_TYPE
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + number, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if(mCursor.getCount() == 0){
                returnValue = false;
            }else{
                returnValue = true;
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }

        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

I am calling this `isPresent()` method with the string which contains `(652) 413-6525` .

Comment: please provide code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your code or database structure, it's difficult to say exactly what the correct way to fix it is.  However it's obvious from the error message that you're trying to use a phone number as a parameter to the `_id` field.

I'm going to go on a limb here and suggest that you want to compare the value to the `number` field.  In which case your query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT _id, number, name, macid, type FROM favorites WHERE number='(652) 413-6525'
```

Notice the single quotes around the phone number.  They are the indicator that you're dealing with a text field rather than a number.

**Update:** you should really be using parametrised query:

```
Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NUMBER, 
                KEY_NAME,
                KEY_MACID,
                KEY_TYPE
                }, 
                KEY_ROWID + "=?", 
                new String[] { number },
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
```

Comment: thanks. you got me there . but i am still getting the exception . Now there is 'number' in place of '_id'